# Fully programmatic hiding / showing of SignPosts

Tags: vmware-clarity

I'm trying to display some extra contextual help as a result of a button click elsewhere (in this case it cant be the trigger)

I'd like to be able to have users dismiss via clicking the close x, or clicking the trigger, but continue to show if users click in places other than the ACTUAL trigger.

I've tried setting `*clrIfOpen="false"` or to about just about any other way I can think of blocking it, but it seems like some place the click listener is just telling isopen service that its open... meaning the `clrIfOpen` is really only good for an initial state.

Any hacks around this?

Comment: Hi there. It sounds like the pattern you are describing is more like a modal. `The signpost is a convenient, lightweight way to show contextual help of information without taking the user out of the current context.` The ClrSignpost is designed to be lightweight and un-obtrusive and removing the ability close on an ouside click makes it more difficult for the user to keep the context behind the Signpost.

Comment: I was hoping to have a signpost display file upload progress in a non blocking fashion... Let users close it... But pop it up by default. I also tried implementing my own component that would inherited from popoverabstract or abstract like the signpost did... But couldn't get angular compiler to resolve reference to the abstractd class ( don't know if it was just not exported or what)

Comment: I see, that is not a pattern Clarity recommends when using a Signpost.

Comment: Clarity's progress bars have many variations, they can be attached to cards, navbar items, ... https://vmware.github.io/clarity/documentation/v0.12/progress
It's all CSS, so I would suggest trying to style a progress bar to render at the bottom of the file input (or whatever triggered the upload) so it's not as intrusive as a tooltip but doesn't clutter the UI. The cards one are a good example, they're completely visible but very thin at the same time.